# Printing Alternatively from arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to print from two arrays a and b alternatively 
a [1,2,3,4]
b [6,7,8,9]

such that 16273849  should be the output.also the input can be string or numbers .All these activities happen inside a function based on a condition.

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: Sounds like a good requirement. Have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this would work:

```
for(int i = 0, i < a.length + b.length; i++){
    if(i%2 == 0){
        System.out.println(a[i/2]);
    }else{
        System.out.println(b[i/2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    System.out.print(a[i]);
    System.out.print(b[i]);
}
```

Comment: I think it should be i++ or you will miss the first element.

Comment: Also this assumes that a.length == b.length. That requirement is ambiguous from the question, but you should still mention it explicitly I think.

Comment: @SeekingAlpha -- nope, the increment part of the for loop is only run at the end of the loop.  It really doesn't matter between i++ and ++i, but I tend to use the prefix out of habit.  Theoretically, ++i could be a hair faster, but any decent compiler should be able to do the optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to interleave the arrays:

```
public void interleave(Object[] a, Object[] b){
  for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    System.out.print(a[i]);
    System.out.print(b[i]);
  }
}
```

This assumes a and b are always the same length. Lets assume that they can be different lengths:

```
public void interleaveVariableLengthArrays(Object[] a, Object[] b){
   int maxLen = Math.max(a.length, b.length);
   for(int i = 0; i < maxLen; i++){
      if(a.length > i){
         System.out.print(a[i]);
      }
      if(b.length > i){
         System.out.print(b[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

Make sure to use System.out.print rather than System.out.println or else you will have carriage returns after each printed element.

Now lets assume that you have a variable number of lists to interleave.

```
public void interleaveVariableLengthAndNumberOfArrays(ArrayList<Object[]> arrays){
    int maxLen = 0;
    for(Object[] array : arrays){
       if(array.length > maxLen){
          maxLen = array.length;
       }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < maxLen; i++){
       for(Object[] array : arrays){
          if(array.length > i){
             System.out.print(a[i]);
          }
       }
    }
}
```